# TextBlock binding doesnt work

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I would like to make a simple WPF app, which contains a Button and a TextBlock in the view. I would like, when i click on the button, write "Hello" to the TextBlock.

Here is my View:

```
<Window x:Class="PropertyTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <Button Name="ButtonIncreaser" Content="Button"  Command="{Binding CalculateCommand}" CommandParameter="+" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="400,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <TextBlock Name="TextB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="56,206,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Szoveg,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="292"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thats MainWindow.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel m = new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = m;
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

And thats my viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public DelegateCommand CalculateCommand { get; private set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        CalculateCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => Calculate(param.ToString()));
    }

    public void Calculate(string param)
    {
        _str = "Hello";
    }

    private string _str;
    private string Szoveg
    {
        get
        {
            return _str;
        }
        set
        {
            _str = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Szoveg");
        }
    }


    public void OnPropertyChanged(String name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        } 
    }
}
```

What do i do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Your `Szoveg` Property is `private`. Needs to be public.

Answer (score 3):

In your `Calculate` function, you're directly setting your private data member `_str`. That doesn't cause the `OnPropertyChanged` function to get called saying that the value of `Szoveg` has changed.

Just change that line to be

```
Szoveg = "Hello"
```

and you should be good.

As XAMIMAX pointed out in the comments, you need to change the `Szoveg` property to be a `public` property as well - [per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx#classes):

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must
>   be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface
>   properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected,
>   private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base
>   implementation.

Additionally, you don't really need the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` part of your binding - that makes sense in some scenarios for a `TextBox` where the user is editing the contents of the `TextBox`. But for a TextBlock it doesn't really make as much sense and is unnecessary in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: private property is not accessible from outside of the class, therefore Binding will fail. Binding was probably highlighted but ignored. :-) @Tim

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. Remember to mark this as the correct answer if it helped you - and to do so on all future questions; it's what keeps SO going!